# Process or Thread level Power Monitoring in Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, pthreads, power-management

I am looking for few tools that can give process or thread level power consumption for the Linux OS. I am looking for something similar to     top    ,    vmstat   ,  mpstat , activity monitor (MAC) etc along with power usage  even if approximate). I have seen a tool for Andorid,  [PowerTutor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=edu.umich.PowerTutor&hl=en)  that does a good job for specific Andorid phones. Are there similar tools that can provide statistics for laptops/desktops etc for the linux OS? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. PowerPack 3.0 is a software developed by Virginia Tech for direct measurements of the power consumption of a system’s major components:
   http://scape.cs.vt.edu/software/powerpack-3-0/
2. The PAPI Api can provide several performance counters:
   http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/overview/index.html
3. Power Analyzer for the ARM processor is a joint venture of the University of Michigan, the University of Colorado:
   http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~panalyzer/

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see exact power values, just a lot of meta information on power (tested od 64bit Mint Maya). Nevertheless it might be useful to you:

> PowerTOP is a Linux tool to diagnose issues with power consumption and power management. In addition to being a diagnostic tool, PowerTOP also has an interactive mode where you can experiment with various power management settings for cases where the Linux distribution has not enabled those settings.
>
> PowerTOP reports which components in the system are most likely to blame for a higher-than-needed power consumption, ranging from software applications to active components in the system. Detailed screens are available for CPU C and P states, device activity, and software activity.
>
> For many years, PowerTOP has been used heavily by Intel, Linux distributors, and various parts of the open source community. We're hoping that our users find the second generation even more useful for their needs.

[homepage](https://01.org/powertop/)

[another article](http://linuxers.org/article/powertop-monitor-power-consumption-your-linux-system-running-intel-platforms)

installation instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install powertop
```

usage instructions

```
sudo powertop
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libnl-dev`, `sudo apt-get install libpci-dev`, download powerTOPv2 from official website https://01.org/powertop/, `./configure; make; sudo make install`